# Google calendar freebusy still requires oauth 2.0 even when calendar is set to be publicly visible

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is there a way to use google calendar api to obtain basic calendar info such as free/busy status? It is a bit pointless that google requires you to go through oauth when I already setup my calendar visibility to public.

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately, what you want cannot be achieved.**

According to the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth):

> Every request your application sends to the Google Calendar API must include an authorization token. The token also identifies your application to Google.

However, the scope required for this offers you read-only access to the Calendar/s.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly
```

#### Reference

- [Authorizing Requests to the Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth)
  .